# Linux Shell Script Illegal number

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I am trying to find out the number of occurrences of pattern in a file with following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

var='grep -c 'abc' file1'

if [ "$var" -lt 10 ]; then
     echo "less than 10"
fi
```

I am getting the error: Illegal number: grep -c abc file1

Can someone please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use backticks (`) instead of apostrophes ('):

```
#!/bin/sh

var=`grep -c 'abc' file1`

if [ "$var" -lt 10 ]; then
     echo "less than 10"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want backticks (`) rather than single-quotes (').  i.e.:

```
var=`grep -c 'abc' file1`
```

Answer (score 1):

You've used a single quote rather than a backtick so your `var` variable is actually set to a string literal rather than the *result* of that command. You'd see that if you echoed the variable first:

```
pax$ var='grep -c 'abc' file1'
pax$ echo "[$var]"
[grep -c abc file1]
```

The backtick version would be:

```
var=`grep -c 'abc' file1`
```

But I'd like to suggest using `bash` where possible for scripting. You'll be hard-pressed finding a mainstream distro that doesn't have it by default and it's considered by some to be more powerful than other shells. In fact, on some systems, `/bin/sh` *is* `bash`.

If you can go that rute, the `$()` construct is usually a better idea since you can nest them without pain:

```
var=$(grep -c 'abc' file1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try posting the followings to get better answer:

- `grep --version`
- `bash --version` if your shell is Bash or let us know which shell you are using.
- use grep within back-ticks or as shown below
- `[[` is more versatile in Bash than `[`.

Finally, the following works on my machine without any error:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(grep -c "abc" file1)
if [[ "$var" -lt 10 ]]
then
    echo "less than 10"
fi
```

Execution:

```
user@machine:~$ cat file1
abc
abcd
abcde
abcdef
user@machine:~$ 
user@machine:~$ ./t.sh 
less than 10
user@machine:~$
```